# How to control the appearance of alternate characters in a font

Tags: fonts, typography, glyphs

I just bought this nice font, and as I was playing around with it I noticed that the last character of each word can be different according the the letter before.

**Here's an example:**

[image: Last character is different]

**My Questions is**

Can I somehow disable this? It was not on the preview when buying the font.

Comment: I did write to them already, no answer yet. But as i couldn't find a online answer i made this post so other people can hopefully find a solution if they are facing same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternative characters (or glyphs) will be controlled by specific [OpenType features](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/using-type-tools/opentype-features). Most likely either ligatures, stylistic alternates or contextual alternates. How you control the use of these features will depend on the software you are using your font with.

For example, in Illustrator you can control which features are used in your text through the OpenType panel:

[image: openType panel]

Or you can manually insert specific characters using the Glyphs panel:

[image: Glyphs panel]

If you want to know how to control these features in the program you are using simply search the documentation for that program for "OpenType features".